# Remove and Add a element on the DOM

Tags: typescript

I helping to create a framework and i need create a directive `cp-if`, different to `cp-show` because in this case a cannot just only change the visibility of the element to 'none' and after just make visible, in the `cp-if` i need create and delete the DOM object

```
import {MapDom} from '../map-dom';
import {Common} from '../../common';

export class CPIf {

 private element: any;
 private map: MapDom;
 private attribute;
 private initialDisplay;

 constructor(_element: HTMLElement, _map: MapDom) {
     this.element = _element;
     this.map = _map;
     this.attribute = Common.getAttributeCpIf(this.element);

     Common.getScope(this.element).$on('$onInit', () => this.init());
 }

 init() {
     try {
         Common.evalInContext(this.attribute, Common.getScope(this.element).scope) ? this.show() : this.hide();
     } catch (ex) {
         this.hide();
     }
 }

 hide() {
     this.element.remove()
 }

 show() {
     console.log(this.element);
 }

}
```

I can remove the object on the DOM, but a can recover when the action go to `show()` function. 
Sorry if a cannot explain my idea very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve using `createComment()` like this

```
import {MapDom} from '../map-dom';
import {Common} from '../../common';

export class CPIf {

 private element: any;
 private map: MapDom;
 private attribute;
 private initialDisplay;
 private elementComment;

 constructor(_element: HTMLElement, _map: MapDom) {
     this.element = _element;
     this.initialDisplay = this.element.style.display || 'block';
     this.map = _map;
     this.attribute = Common.getAttributeCpIf(this.element);
     this.elementComment = document.createComment('cpIf ' + this.attribute);
     Common.getScope(this.element).$on('$onInit', () => this.init());
 }

 init() {
     try {
         Common.evalInContext(this.attribute, Common.getScope(this.element).scope) ? this.show() : this.hide();
     } catch (ex) {
         this.hide();
     }
 }

 hide() {
     this.element.replaceWith(this.elementComment);
 }

 show() {
     this.elementComment.replaceWith(this.element);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your solution, but I had this problem recently and solved it a different way.

Although the linter didn't recognize the method `.remove()` method on the type `HTMLElement`, it did recognize `.removeChild()`, so I ended up creating a family chain up to the grandparent element, which then called `removeChild` on its child element. It looked like this:

(if statement is here to prevent the linter from complaining that the object might be null)

`if (listItemElement && listItemElement.parentNode && listItemElement.parentNode.parentNode) {
  listItemElement.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(listItemElement.parentNode);
}`

Not a pretty solution, but it works and I figure at some point, the linter will recognize the much more straightforward `.remove()` method, which will simplify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use removeChild() to remove DOM element from parentNode.
remove() will not work on IE browser so use removeChild() and it will work on all browser.
        element.parentNode.removeChild(this);